# Bootstrap dropdown menu not appearing

Tags: jquery, menu, nav, dropdown

My dropdown menu in Bootstrap doesnt appear to be working - can anyone alert me to the problem? Right now it displays the dropdown icon when less than 768px wide, but clicking it does nothing. Thanks!

```
<header>
    <div class="navbar-wrapper"></div>
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Bootstrap to Wordpress"></a>   
                    </div><!-- navbar header -->
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                          <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div><!-- navbar-collapse -->
                </div><!-- navbar-container -->
            </div><!-- navbar-inner -->
        </div><!-- navbar -->
    </div><!-- navbar-wrapper -->
</header>
```

Code from body section:

```
<!-- BOOTSTRAP CORE JAVASCRIPT
        Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster.
========================================================== -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<script src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try changing the: data-toggle=".navbar-collapse". You don't have any such id in your HTML, so # is not going to work.

Comment: While technically ``data-toggle=".navbar-collapse"`` would work it's best practice to use an ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your navbar by giving it an ID like so`<div id="myNav" class="navbar-collapse collapse">` then call that ID with `data-target`, ie `data-target="#myNav"`

CodePen working [demo](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/MaQRPJ?editors=100)

Full Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNav" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Bootstrap to Wordpress"></a>  
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
         <div id="myNav" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div><!-- navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->    
    </div>
</nav>
```

Media Queries for Specific Bootstrap breakpoints.

```
/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks Petrus! You are a legend. Can I just quickly ask then what class I would call in CSS to style the expanded dropdown nav-bar as it is a has picked up the styles from the horizontal navbar? I'm thinking it'd be .navbar-collapse#myNav but not 100% sure.

Comment: No problem man! Bootstrap is built responsive and navbars, columns, etc will collapse at specific breakpoints depending on your viewport. You can actually use media queries to target the specific viewports and when your navbar collapses. Use these media queries and add your own CSS to them.